# Need help trying to calculate averages based on user input. C

Tags: c, average

```
int main() {
int miles_ran, i;
float miles_ran_time, avg_time, sum;

//ask's user for how many miles they ran
printf("How many miles did you run?\n");
scanf("%d", &miles_ran);

//ask's the user for each time that it took them to run each mile
//loop continues asking for each of their time depending on the number inputed above
for (i = 1; i <= miles_ran; i++){
    printf("\nHow long did it take you to run mile #%d\n", i);
    scanf("%d", &miles_ran_time);
}

printf("\nYour average time to run a mile is %.3f.\n", avg_time);

return 0;
}
```

I need help in trying to get the average for each of the different times that a user would input. I cannot seem to figure out how to go about it. For example, if the user were to input that they ran 3 miles and their time for the 3 miles was 10, 10.5, and 9; the average would come out to 9.83.

Answer (score 1):

Simply sum up all the times you read in and divide by the total miles ran:

```
sum = 0;

for (i = 1; i <= miles_ran; i++){
    printf("\nHow long did it take you to run mile #%d\n", i);
    scanf("%d", &miles_ran_time);
    sum += miles_ran_time;
}

avg_time = sum / miles_ran;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your own homework!

How did you come up with your 9.83?  You added all the numbers together and divided by the number of miles so do the same thing in your code.  Keep a running sum in the loop (sum += miles_ran_time;) then compute avg_time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum the times and divide them with the number of miles.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
        int miles_ran, i;
        float miles_ran_time, avg_time, sum;
        float time  = 0;

        //ask's user for how many miles they ran
        printf("How many miles did you run?\n");
        scanf("%d", &miles_ran);

        //ask's the user for each time that it took them to run each mile
        //loop continues asking for each of their time depending on the number inputed above
        for (i = 1; i <= miles_ran; i++){
            printf("\nHow long did it take you to run mile #%d\n", i);
            scanf("%f", &miles_ran_time);
            time += miles_ran_time;
        }

        printf("\nYour average time to run a mile is %.3f.\n", time/miles_ran);

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A few basic errors. See inline comments below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int miles_ran=0, i=0;      /* initialize your variables */
int c;
float miles_ran_time=0.0, avg_time=0.0, sum=0;

//ask's user for how many miles they ran
printf("How many miles did you run?\n");
scanf("%d", &miles_ran);
do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF );        /* flush input buffer after scanf */

//ask's the user for each time that it took them to run each mile
//loop continues asking for each of their time depending on the number inputed above
for (i = 1; i <= miles_ran; i++){
    printf("\nHow long did it take you to run mile #%d\n", i);
    scanf("%f", &miles_ran_time);                       
    do { c=getchar(); } while ( c != '\n' && c != EOF );    /* flush input buffer after scanf */
    sum += miles_ran_time;                                  /* compute 'sum' from miles ran time */
}

avg_time = sum / miles_ran;                                 /* compute average */

printf("\nYour average time to run a mile is %.3f.\n", avg_time);

return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/avg
How many miles did you run?
5

How long did it take you to run mile #1
10.1

How long did it take you to run mile #2
9

How long did it take you to run mile #3
9.5

How long did it take you to run mile #4
9.8

How long did it take you to run mile #5
9.7

Your average time to run a mile is 9.620.
```